# Many-To-Many relationships with EFCore and C# 5.0 : how to get the fields from the both of tables

Tags: entity-framework-core, linqpad, ef-core-5.0

I have the following database in PostgreSQL[image: ER Schema]
EDIT: there is an Unique Key in PizzaTopping built with the fields Id_Pizza, Id_Topping

As you can see it's a Many-To-Many relationship.

When I ask Linqpad 6 to scaffold from my Database I have the following result:

[image: Linqpad6 result]

The same result I have it when I use the EFCore Power Tools when I ask them to reverse engineer my database.

Reading from various sources, I've found, to ask EFCore to get the list of the toppings of the pizzas I should do something like that:

```
Pizzas.Where(p=>p.Description=="Margherita")
      .Include(p=>p.PizzaToppings)
      .ThenInclude(p=>p.IdToppingNavigation)
```

The query EFCore 5 returns this query:

```
SELECT P."Id_Pizza",
       P."Description",
       T0."Id_PizzaTopping",
       T0."Id_Pizza",
       T0."Id_Topping",
       T0."Id_Topping0",
       T0."Description"
FROM "Pizza" AS P
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT P0."Id_PizzaTopping",
            P0."Id_Pizza",
            P0."Id_Topping",
            T."Id_Topping" AS "Id_Topping0",
            T."Description"
     FROM "PizzaTopping" AS P0
     INNER JOIN "Topping" AS T ON P0."Id_Topping" = T."Id_Topping") AS T0 ON P."Id_Pizza" = T0."Id_Pizza"
WHERE P."Description" = 'Margherita'
ORDER BY P."Id_Pizza",
         T0."Id_PizzaTopping",
         T0."Id_Topping0"
```

Since I want to return a list with Pizza, topping like:

```
margherita, mozzarella
margherita, tomato sauce
marinara, garlic
marinara, tomato sauce
```

I tried with add .Select(topping=>topping.description) but it gets the pizza description.

So how can I take the toppings descriptions who they are in the topping table?
I tried to put a .Select() after the .ThenInclude() but I still see the Pizza entity and the p.PizzaToppings does not contain the property description of the topping table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you do not need `Include` but `SelectMany` with custom projection:

```cs
var query = 
   from p in Pizzas
   from pt in p.PizzaToppings
   select new 
   {
      Pizza = p.Description,
      Topping = pt.IdToppingNavigation.Description
   }
```